# Fetch the nearest city, optimised with Redis on a Lambda

Tags: javascript, lambda, postgresql, redis

I have a lambda function which returns the nearest city from a latitude and longitude.

My algorithm for this is resource heavy and time consuming. To optimise this, I hash the coordinates into a 6 digit combination representing the 5km tile they are in. For example 'apHsvW' might refer to New York.

I save the hash in a postgres database, and also Redis. I want Redis to be the first choice and then fallback on the database and then the algorithm as a last resort.

Here is my lambda code:

```
const database = require( './database' )
database.connect()

const redis = require( './redis' )
redis.connect()

exports.handler = async ( event, context ) => {
  const get = require( 'lodash.get' )
  const set = require( 'lodash.set' )

  //Params
  const { latitude, longitude } = get( event, 'queryStringParameters' ) || event || {}
  const invalid = isNaN( latitude ) || isNaN( longitude )
  if ( invalid ) return response( 200, 'Invalid params' )

  console.log( `Getting city for ${ latitude }, ${ longitude }` )
  set( context, 'callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop', false )
  
  //Hash their coordinates to get their tile
  const precision = process.env.PRECISION || 6
  const hash = require( './hash' ).encode( latitude, longitude, precision )
  console.log( `Got hash: ${ hash }` )

  //See if redis has the city for this hash
  console.log( `Checking redis for hash` )
  const cached = await redis.get( 'grid', hash ).catch( e => console.log( e ))
  if ( cached ) return response( 200, cached )
  
  //Check the database after
  console.log( `Checking database for ${ hash }` )
  const saved = await database.grid.get( hash )
  if ( saved ) {
    await redis.set( 'grid', hash, saved ).catch( e => console.log( e ))
    return response( 200, saved )
  }

  //Get the most suitable city
  console.log( `Running algorithm` )
  const city = await getCity( latitude, longitude )

  const { id, name, country, code } = city
  const data = { id, name, country, code }

  console.log( `City result: ${ id }, ${ name }, ${ country }` )

  //Save to database and redis in parallel
  await Promise.allSettled([
    database.grid.set( hash, id ),
    redis.set( 'grid', hash, data )
  ]).catch( e => console.log( e ))

  return response( 200, data )
}
```

Here is my database connection function located in './database'

```
let database

module.exports = {
  connect: () => {
    database = require( 'knex' )({
      client: process.env.DATABASE_CLIENT || 'postgres',
      connection: {
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost',
        user: process.env.DATABASE_USER || 'admin',
        password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME || 'postgres'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

And here is my redis file at './redis'

```
const get = require( 'lodash.get' )
let client

module.exports = {
  connect: () => {
    console.log( '\nConnecting to Redis' )

    //Create Redis client with env variables
    const redis = require( 'redis' )
    const { REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT } = process.env
    client = redis.createClient({ host: REDIS_HOST, port: REDIS_PORT })

    client.on( 'error', e => console.log( e ))
    client.on( 'ready', () => console.log( 'Connected' ))

    return client
  },

  get: ( set, key ) => {
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
      if ( !get( client, 'connected' )) return reject( 'Not connected to redis' )
      client.hget( set, key, ( e, res ) => ( e ) ? reject( e ) : resolve( JSON.parse( res )))
    })
  },

  set: ( set, key, value ) => {
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
      if ( !get( client, 'connected' )) return reject( 'Not connected to redis' )
      client.hmset( set, key, JSON.stringify( value ), e => ( e ) ? reject( e ) : resolve() )
    })
  }
}
```

These are the following issues that im mainly concerned about

1. Should my Db and Redis connections be defined outside of the handler?, I read it was good practise as it keeps the connection open for the next request.
2. Do I need `set( context, 'callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop', false )` to do this? I read that this should be done to keep Redis open, but im not sure if it applys to the db connection too
3. Would it be better to close the connection after im finished?
4. Since im not waiting for the success event from redis to know if its connected, Will the code potentially run before its finished connecting? I cant await it outside the handler.

I would also like any feedback in general to optimise this code further, even the smallest thing.

Thankyou very much